# Unable to find the profiler in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am facing the problem of finding SQL Server Profiler in SQL Server 2005. Is there are any options to enable it or to reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was because I had installed Management Studio **Express** before I installed the full version. You can't have more than one instance of Management Studio, therefore, it won't install the full version over the express version. I found that I had to remove the express SSMS and then install the full SSMS:-

1. Go to Control Panel/Programs and Features (in Windows 7)
2. At "Select an instance", choose "Remove Shared Features Only"
3. Choose "Management Tools - Basic"

You can then run the installer again and install the FULL SSMS. Dunno if this was the problem you were having, but hopefully someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities.

First, you're running Sql Server Express.  That doesn't come with Profiler.  In that case, you can use [this tool](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/), which is an open source version that is pretty good.  I've used it a few times myself (not associated with the project, spamflaggers).

Else, you need to rerun the installer and add Profiler.  If it didn't get installed, it has to be installed.  That's the general state of things in the software world.

Answer (score 1):

You can select SQL Server Profiler from the Tools menu in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: there is no sql profiler in my sql server tools. that is problem, i am asking in my question

Comment: What version you are using ? If it is Express edition. then it will not show up

Answer (score 1):

The file is located on my computer under:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\PROFILER90.EXE"
```

If its not there you may have to select the client tools from the SQL Server installer.

Simply navigate to add/remove programs, and click 'change' on the SQL Server 2005.

Comment: means i have to install it again ?

Comment: No, you should be able to modify the install from here. It may look like its re-installing, but it will just be updating